# How to write valid XPath expression using AND condition

Tags: selenium, xpath, contains

On multiple environments of the app which we are testing, the ID of one element is different. I have this div ID

**CoredataForm:sec2_natural:grid1:left_section_natural:profession:selectProfession**_auto_complete_force:**ajax**

Bold marked parts of the id, is the part which is same for all the environments.

How should I write xpath expression which would fit to all of them?
I used this

```
xpath="//div[starts-with(@id,'CoredataForm:sec2_natural:grid1:left_section_natural:profession:selectProfession') and ends-with(@id,'ajax')]"
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe another question: how can I use `contains()` function with multiple wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath might not work if your tool supports XPath1.0 only cause `fn:ends-with` is not available in XPath1.0

You can try to replace `ends-with` with `contains` in your XPath as

```
"//div[starts-with(@id,'CoredataForm:sec2_natural:grid1:left_section_natural:profession:selectProfession') and contains(@id,'ajax')]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium supports only XPath 1, but as JaSON says, `ends-with` is only available in XPath 2 and later versions.

However, it's possible to check that a string ends with another string using just the XPath 1 functions `substring` and `string-length`. The `substring` function returns a substring starting at a particular character location. The first character in the string has position `0`, so `substring('abc', 1)`=`'bc'`

If a string `$s1` ends with another string`$s2`, then the following is true:

`substring($s1, string-length($s1) - string-length($s2)) = $s2`

So this expression should work for you (broken into multiple lines, for readability):

```xml
//div[
   starts-with(
      @id,
      'CoredataForm:sec2_natural:grid1:left_section_natural:profession:selectProfession'
   ) 
   and 
   substring(
      @id, 
      string-length(@id) - string-length('ajax')
   ) = 'ajax'
]
```

Comment: You could put the predicate on the @id like this div[@id[here the same logic but using the .]], to make it less redundant